# JUnit error "test framework quit unexpectedly" in Intelij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, gherkin

I've investigated this issue from different sides, but didn't get anywhere so far. I have a project that runs selenium driver on JUnit using Cucumber for Java. I use **Maven**.
Here's my **TestRunner** that runs the test:

```
package com.task.lab;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "C:\\Users\\admin\\IdeaProjects\\bddtesting\\src\\test\\java\\com\\task\\lab\\features",
        glue = "C:\\Users\\admin\\IdeaProjects\\bddtesting\\src\\test\\java\\com\\task\\lab\\steps")
public class TestRunner {
}
```

Here's feature file:

```
Feature: Login to Gmail

 Scenario Outline: login compose and delete letter
    Given: User is on SignIn page
    When: User enters <Email> and <Password>
    Then: User sends letter to <Receiver> and alert is displayed letter is sent
Examples:
  |Email                 |Password   |Receiver
  |testaccount@gmail.com |okokokokok |testtest@gmail.com
  |testaccount@gmail.com |okokokokok |testtest@gmail.com
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.task.lab.bddtesting</groupId>
<artifactId>bddtesting</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And finally my Steps.Defs class:

```
package com.task.lab.steps;

import com.task.lab.decorator.bo.businessobjects.GmailMessage;
import com.task.lab.decorator.bo.businessobjects.Login;
import com.task.lab.driver.DriverObject;
import com.task.lab.propertyreader.ReadPropertyFile;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class StepDefs {

private Login login = new Login();

@Given("^User is on SignIn page$")
public void openSignInPage(){
    LOG.info("Logging in");
    DriverObject.getDriver();
    DriverObject.getDriver().get(ReadPropertyFile.readGmailURL());
}

@When("^User enters (\\S+) and (\\S+)$")
public void enterCredentials(String email, String password) throws Throwable {
    login = new Login();
    login.login(email, password);
}

@Then("^User sends letter to (\\S+) and alert is displayed letter is sent$")
public void composeLetter(String receiver){
    GmailMessage gmail = new GmailMessage();
    gmail.sendMessage(receiver);
}

@After
public void closeBrowser(){
    DriverObject.releaseThread();
}
}
```

When I try to run the TestRunner from the window I get the error **No tests were found**. As I investigated priorly, the reason for this could be that I run Test Unit, not Main class. So I reconfigured Intelij Setting for this project to run from **Cucumber for Java** and specified the Main class as `cucumber.api.cli.Main`. However, this gives me another error `Test framework quit unexpectedly`. I also tried running features file only and in this case tests are green but in fact, no scenarios or steps are passed, as the output in the console shows:

```
0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0,000s
```

I also reinstalled my Intelij to Ultimate version, but the result is just the same. Could someone please help me see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attached.

Comment: Please note the cucumber version you are using is quite old. Look [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm) for the most recent version. Note that the group-id changed for v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I suspected the issue was minor. In my future file  I removed ":" and closed my table with vertical lines "|":

```
Feature: Login to Gmail

 Scenario Outline: login compose and delete letter
    Given User is on SignIn page
    When User enters <Email> and <Password>
    Then User sends letter to <Receiver> and alert is displayed letter is sent
Examples:
  |Email                 |Password   |Receiver          |
  |testaccount@gmail.com |okokokokok |testtest@gmail.com|
  |testaccount@gmail.com |okokokokok |testtest@gmail.com|
```

Worked like a charm.